# IOException when Uploading Videos to YouTube via Java API

Tags: java, youtube

I have been attempting to upload videos to YouTube via the JavaAPI using Direct Uploading.  I have been having a problem when I call the insert() method, I get a IOException with the error message

"Error writing request body to the server"

I have verified that the File object I am creating is correct as well as all the details in my VideoEntry object.  I have been using Fiddler to monitor the activity from my machine and no request is made to the upload API so the problem is not there.  Here is a summary of the code I am using:

```
VideoEntry newVideo = new VideoEntry();
//Defined video properties such as title and description here.
MediaFileSource ms = new MediaFileSource(videoFile, "video/flv");
newVideo.setMediaSource(ms);
VideoEntry createdEntry = settings.insert(new URL(apiUrl), newVideo);
```

The IOException is thrown on the insert call (settings is my YouTubeService instance) and the API URL appears to be correct.

Prior to this I have succeeded in uploading this video using the C# API so I know the video file is valid.

--Update
This is the apiURL value:

http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads

Comment: Yes, every time I try and run this code it fails

Comment: Can I see how 'apiUrl' is created?

Comment: me having the same issue.... did u get the solution for the same...and if yes can u share plz..

Answer (score 0):

Make certain that videoFile actually points to the correct local file.  The File(String) constructor won't verify that it actually exists.  The MediaFileSource constructor and VideoEntry.setMediaSource() method also never check that the file is valid.  The error message "Error writing request body to the server" sounds like the insert method can not find the body of the message it is trying to send.

```
File videoFile = new File("...");
if (videoFile.exists() == false) {
    System.err.println("FAIL");
}
```

to test if the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you are under a firewall env and had configured your proxy settings in jvm system properties. The try configuring your youtube service as:

```
service.setChunkedMediaUpload(MediaService.NO_CHUNKED_MEDIA_REQUEST);
```

or in your case

```
settings.setChunkedMediaUpload(MediaService.NO_CHUNKED_MEDIA_REQUEST);
```

since as you say is your YouTubeService instance.

hope this helps.